# Webpack (4) hot module reloading fetches update manifest from malformed URI

Tags: webpack, webpack-hmr

When Webpack attempts to fetch the update JSON file, it fails with the console error message:

```
[HMR] Update failed: Error: Manifest request to https://subdomain.localhost23dae8e1865781c26fcd.hot-update.json timed out.
```

Note the omission of a slash between the TLD and the path…

**Devserver config:**

```
{
  public: `subdomain.localhost`,
  publicPath: 'https://subdomain.localhost/',
  port: 9000,
  https: false,
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname),
  watchContentBase: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  compress: true,
  hot: true
};
```

*What configuration is required to ensure update manifest will load from the correct path?*

- No other parts of our dev/prod environments are failing… which leads
  me to believe the configuration error exists in a niche.
- https://subdomain.localhost/webpack-dev-server links to valid assets
  at the correct URL's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly, the hot module replacement plugin will actually look to the `config.output.publicPath` property *rather than* the `config.devServer.[static].publicPath` value.

`devServer.static.publicPath` (or WDS < 4, `devServer.publicPath`) should be the *same* as `output.publicPath`.

Correcting the output property to use the full path `https://subdomain.localhost/` corrects this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `publicPath` should be just `/` instead of the full path.

Comment: From the docs: "To teach webpack to make requests (for chunk loading or HMR) to the webpack-dev-server you need to provide a full URL in the output.publicPath option." See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/webpack-dev-server

Comment: full url here means the absolute path, but not including the domain name. see for example the first code block in the link you attach here, `publicPath` is "/assets/", not "https://subdomain.localhost/assets/"